# エラーの意味がわかりません: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: haskell

sample.hs という名前のファイルに、ifのみを使って3つの数字の中で一番大きな数を出力する関数 `maxif3(x,y,z)` を以下のように作りました。

```
max3if(x,y,z)=if x>y>z then x 
              else if x>z>y then x
              else if y>x>z then y
              else if y>z>x then y
              else if z>x>y then z
              else if z>y>x then z
```

しかし、コンパイルしたとき、このようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
Prelude> :l sample.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( sample.hs, interpreted )

sample.hs:187:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

自分のプログラムについて、どこが間違っているのかがわからなかったので聞いた次第です。
また、できればエラーの意味も教えてほしいです。お願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` は必ず `then` と `else` の両方が必要です。エラーの意味は、適切にインデントされた `else` を期待しており、`else` 以前にインデントがおかしいので `incorrect indentation` と表示されています。

プログラムの意味は一旦考えずにおいて、このエラーに対処するには次のようなコードになります。

```
max3if(x,y,z)=if x>y>z then x 
              else if x>z>y then x
              else if y>x>z then y
              else if y>z>x then y
              else if z>x>y then z
              else if z>y>x then z
              else x
```

しかしこのコードにはまだエラーがあります。1つだけ掲載すると下記です。同じエラーが複数あります。

```
sample.hs:1:18: error:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix ‘>’ [infix 4] and ‘>’ [infix 4] in the same infix expression
  |
1 | max3if(x,y,z)=if x>y>z then x
  |
```

`>` 関数に結合性がないにもかかわらず連続した書いているのがいけません。これは次のように書く必要があります。

```
max3if(x,y,z)=if x>y && y>z then x 
              else if x>z && z>y then x
              else if y>x && x>z then y
              else if y>z && z>x then y
              else if z>x && x>y then z
              else if z>y && y>x then z
              else x
```

これで構文エラー、型エラーともになくなり実行できます。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。いくつもの大小関係を比較するとき、不等号を中に連続して入力するのではなく、＆＆を挟むということは初めて知りました。